# DLM package, State equation

Tags: r, dlm

I would like to know how can I write in dlm form ( dlm PAckage by Petris) a state equation like this:

$$a(t+1) = k(t) + F*a(t) + T(t)w(t)$$

where $w$ is $N(0,1)$.

To make it easier I can assume $k$ and $T$ constant.
My question is how can I rearrange it in the way described by "An R Package for Dynamic Linear Models"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w(t)$ is $N(0,1)$ you can define $w^*(t) = T(t)w(t)$ which will have covariance matrix $Q(t)= T(t)T(t)'$; you can always subsume the $T(t)$ part in the covariance matrix of the random vector $w(t)$ which drives the state equation.

As for the $k(t)$ part, which you are willing to assume constant, you might perhaps augment the state vector and write:

$ \qquad\qquad\begin{bmatrix} a(t+1) \\ k(t+1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} F & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a(t) \\ k(t) \end{bmatrix} + 
 \begin{bmatrix} w^*(t) \\ \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$

with the augmented noise vector having distribution normal, with mean vector $\vec{0}$ and covariance matrix

$\qquad\qquad Q =  \begin{bmatrix} T(t)T(t)' & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$

If you initialize the filter with whatever prior you use for the $a(t)$ part and $N(k,0)$ for the $k(t)$ element of the state vector, it will take value $k$ for all $t$. I think `dlm` will cope with the singular matrices above, but have no chance to test at my present location.